# How to suspend the execution of a QThread upon a QPushButton press?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qthread

I'm writing a simple GUI for the Lights Out Board ([Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_%28game%29)) using PyQt4. The GUI has a 'Solve' Button which uses Iterative Deepening Depth First Search. This being time consuming, I spawn a new QThread to solve for the puzzle and update the board when it finishes while the GUI remains responsive. This I'm able to do.

But, I also have a 'Stop' Button which should stop the Search thread if it is currently running and I'm unable to stop the QThread using the exit(). Here's the code for the three functions.

```
class LightsOut(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # Whole other initialization stuff
        self.pbStart.clicked.connect(self.puzzleSolver) # The 'Start' Button
        self.pbStop.clicked.connect(self.searchStop) # The 'Stop' Button

    def searchStop(self):
        if self.searchThread.isRunning():
            self.searchThread.exit() # This isn't working
            self.tbLogWindow.append('Stopped the search !') # This is being printed
        else:
            self.tbLogWindow.append('Search is not running')

    def searchFinish(self):
        self.loBoard.setBoard() # Redraw the lights out board with solution

    def puzzleSolver(self):
        maxDepth = self.sbMaxDepth.value() # Get the depth from Spin Box
        self.searchThread = SearchThread(self.loBoard, self.tbLogWindow, maxDepth)
        self.searchThread.finished.connect(self.searchFinish)
        self.tbLogWindow.append('Search started')
        self.searchThread.start()
```

When I click the 'Stop' Button, in the Log Window (QTextBrowser), I can see 'Stopped the search' message, but my CPU is still running at 100% and when the search finishes, the solution is being displayed (searchFinish is being called). Obviously, I'm missing something very simple, and I haven't used terminate() as it is frowned upon in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`terminate()`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qthread.html#terminate) instead of `quit` and call [`wait()`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qthread.html#wait). `wait()` will block until the QThread has finished.

Another thing you could do is to set a quit condition outside the thread which you will check for inside the thread (Probably the best solution). Additionally you can connect a slot to the `finished` signal.

Comment: Thanks, terminate worked. The second solution though works doesn't look like a smart choice as it needs me to edit another part of code which is well tested and it would also increase coupling in the modules.

Comment: If my solution helped you, you can mark is a the correct answer.